# Unset Command in Linux does not clear the Variable

Tags: linux, environment-variables, csh, unset

I am trying to unset a variable in Linux, but the `unset` command isn't working.

```
[jisip@slc10xxx plsql]$ echo $PERL5LIB
/net/slcnasxxx.in.ecalor.com/export/xxx/bin
[jisip@slc10xxx plsql]$ unset PERL5LIB
[jisip@slc10xxx plsql]$ echo $PERL5LIB
/net/slcnasxxx.in.ecalor.com/export/xxx/bin
```

Any ideas or alternatives?

Comment: Are you doing this in the same subshell? Post contents of `PROMPT_COMMAND`.

Comment: what if you do this `PERL5LIB='`'or `PERL5LIB=` ,this will also clear the contents of variable! did my method worked for you?

Comment: Unable to reproduce this in bash.  unset works fine

Answer (score 2):

I was able to resolve this by using `unsetenv` instead of `unset`.

```
[jisip@slc10xxx plsql]$ unsetenv PERL5LIB
[jisip@slc10xxx plsql]$ echo $PERL5LIB                                                                                                                                                                   
PERL5LIB: Undefined variable.
[jisip@slc10xxx plsql]$
```

Hope this helps out!

Comment: Which shell are you using: csh, bash, etc?

Comment: @TimurShtatland csh